# How to convert datetime to different timezone?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-datetime, pytz

I'm trying to convert a datetime string into a different timezone. My code works but the result is not what I'm looking for.

I've already tried `.localize()` and `.astimezone` but the output is the same.

```
phtimezone = timezone('Asia/Manila')
test = datetime.datetime.strptime('Sun Sep 16 03:38:40 +0000 2018','%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
date = phtimezone.localize(test)
print (date) 
date = test.astimezone(phtimezone)
print (date)
```

The output is `2018-09-16 03:38:40+08:00`. I was expecting it to be `2018-09-16 11:38:40+08:00.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parsed object `test` does not contain a timezone. It's a naïve `datetime` object. Using both `localize` and `astimezone` cannot do any conversion, since they don't know what they're converting from; so they just attach the timezone as given to the naïve `datetime`.

Also parse the timezone:

```
datetime.strptime('Sun Sep 16 03:38:40 +0000 2018','%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
                                                                      ^^
```

This gives you an *aware* `datetime` object in the UTC timezone which can be *converted* to other timezones.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it thanks to @deceze. Here is the code:

```
phtimezone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Manila')
test = datetime.datetime.strptime('Sun Sep 16 03:38:40 +0000 2018','%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
test_utc = test.replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))
date = test_utc.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Asia/Manila'))
print (date)
```

The output is now `2018-09-16 11:38:40+08:00`